# Is there a way to make the text color in a TextInput in kivy to be dependent on the background?

Tags: python, kivy

I am using Kivy's TextInput and Ihave a background image behind it.
Since there is a background image - the text above it is not clear (i.e. black text on black background etc.).

Is there a way to make the text color to be the opposite from the background behind it?

Note that the background is not a solid color image, but a regular image. Thanks!

Also, i would like to have text outline so it will be more readable. Tried the text_outline property but it is for labels and not for textInputs, Is there an alternative?

Again, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General algorithm may be as follows:

1. find average color of your image
2. find a complimentary or contrast color
3. set the color of the text_input to contrast color.

The implementation of 1 and 2 can be quite complex.
In this example, I will show only a rough sketch. Of course, you can find or implement more efficient functions.

1. find the dominant color of the image:

```
from PIL import Image as I

def average_color(image_fn):
    im = I.open(image_fn)
    im = im.convert('RGB')
    #comment the above if you don't use images with opacity

    new_im = im.resize((1, 1))
    pixels = new_im.getpixel((0, 0))
    print pixels
    return pixels
```

This is very-very rough way.
I suggested that an image has a square-like shape.
Then using PIL, I simply change its size to 1 pixel (1x1), then I got rgb color of this pixel.

2. find a complimentary/contrast color.

```
from colorsys import rgb_to_hls as rgb2hls
from colorsys import hls_to_rgb as hls2rgb

def contrast(rgb):
    h,l,s = rgb2hls(*rgb)
    new_l = 0 if l>=0.5 else 1
    new_rgb = hls2rgb(h, new_l,s)
    return new_rgb
```

This function gets an RGB pixel, then translates it into HLS, then sets Lightness to 0 or 1 (as far as possible from the current value), then translates it back into RGB, and returns this value. So we get white or black text color, depending on which one is more contrast to the current image.

Now let's add these algorithms to a kivy application:

```
from __future__ import division

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.core.window import Window

from PIL import Image as I

from colorsys import rgb_to_hls as rgb2hls
from colorsys import hls_to_rgb as hls2rgb


KV = """
FloatLayout
    MyImage
        id: image
        text_input:text_input
        #source: 'im.png'

    MyTextInput
        id: text_input

<MyTextInput@TextInput>
    font_size: 40
    background_normal : ''
    background_active: ''
    background_color: 0,0,0,0
    text: 'this is some text. Drag and drop an image here. '*20
"""



def average_color(image_fn):
    im = I.open(image_fn)
    im = im.convert('RGB')
    #comment the above if you don't use images with opacity

    new_im = im.resize((1, 1))
    pixels = new_im.getpixel((0, 0))
    print pixels
    return pixels




def contrast(rgb):
    h,l,s = rgb2hls(*rgb)
    new_l = 0 if l>=0.5 else 1
    new_rgb = hls2rgb(h, new_l,s)
    return new_rgb


class MyImage(Image):
    def on_source(self, inst, fn): 
        aver = [i/255 for i in average_color(fn)]
        contrast_rgba = [i for i in contrast(aver)]+[1]
        self.text_input.foreground_color = contrast_rgba


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(KV)
        Window.bind(on_dropfile=self.manage_dropfile)

    def is_image(self, fn):
        if fn[-4:] in ['.png', '.jpg', 'jpeg']: return True
        return False

    def manage_dropfile(self, window, fn):
        fn = fn.decode('UTF-8')
        if self.is_image(fn):
            self.root.ids.image.source = fn

MyApp().run()
```

The most important thing is that we created a class MyImage, in which in on_source() method (on each change of image source) we get the average color value, then a contrast color and finally we change foreground_color.

Also I implemented a dragndrop of images. You can drop any jpg/png image file from some folder on your computer, and the text will automatically change its color to black or white.
[image]

Comment: Thank you kind stranger! that solution is great!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to change the text color as you describe. Do you mean that you want the text color to change according to what is behind it? Like the top of an `E` could be white, while the bottom of the same `E` could be black?

But I think you can add the outline property to `TextInput` by sub-classing it:

```
from kivy.core.text import Label
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

class TextInputOutline(TextInput):
    outline_width = NumericProperty(0)
    outline_color = ListProperty((0,0,0))

    def _get_line_options(self):
        # Get or create line options, to be used for Label creation
        if self._line_options is None:
            self._line_options = kw = {
                'font_size': self.font_size,
                'font_name': self.font_name,
                'anchor_x': 'left',
                'anchor_y': 'top',
                'padding_x': 0,
                'padding_y': 0,
                'padding': (0, 0),
                'outline_width': self.outline_width,
                'outline_color': self.outline_color}
            self._label_cached = Label(**kw)
        return self._line_options
```

The `_get_line_options` method above over-rides the same method in `TextInput`. The only difference is the inclusion of the `outline` properties. With this `TextInputOutline` you can specify an outline thickness and color, like:

```
TextInputOutline:
    text: 'This is a Test'
    foreground_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
    outline_color: (0, 0, 0)
    outline_width: 1
```

Note that this over-rides a method that starts with `_`, so there is no guarantee that this will still work if `TextInput` gets changed in some future `Kivy` update.

Comment: Thanks! that's a nice way around the text input class. I'll use that :)